# R matching multiple negative lookahead and negative lookbehind

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

When I match multiple negative lookahead or multiple negative lookbehind, I find that R's behavior is different. To illustrate, suppose I want to match anything following z except a, d, bd, or bcd in str. The following regex works:

```
grep("z(?!a|(bc?)?d)",str,perl=TRUE)
```

Next, I want to match anything preceding z except a, b, bd, or bcd in str. A regex constructed in the similar way fails (invalid regex):

```
grep("(?<!a|b(c?d)?)z",str,perl=TRUE)
```

Consequently I have to use a rather cumbersome regex:

```
grep("(?<!a|b)(?<!bd)(?<!bcd)z",str,perl=TRUE)
```

It seems that in the case of (negative) lookbehind, if I wan to use the "or" operator |, the subexpressions must be of equal length, but there is no such limitation in the case of (negative) lookahead.

Do I miss anything here? My problem is I have many patterns to match in the negative lookbehind case. Using | and ? would substantially simplify the regular expression, but for the reasons stated above I cannot use them. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Yeah, variable length matches inside a single lookbehind is prohibited in many engines. If you have many strings to put in lookbehind like that, you can probably use a vector instead and dynamically construct the pattern from that, if you want.

Comment: As CertainPerformance said, this is often not a supported feature in regex engines. C#/.NET is a notable exception, but it's not like you're going to to switch languages just for this. However, there could be a simpler solution here. If you post the full context of what you're trying to do, maybe we can come up with a solution that doesn't involve variable length lookbehind.

Comment: Thank you both for clarifying this issue to me. In my case (processing address data), the patterns are manually set to pick up certain irregularities. There is little rule to follow. Therefore, I have to input the patterns manually. It's tedious but still manageable.